# How to create a layout any suggestions please?

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

I have attached a layout file below how to create a layout like this. The list should be created at the runtime ? I can enable check box which ever required and when I click on submit button details should be saved.
Any suggestions would be helpful for me. thanks in advance :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCp6X.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

1) You have to Create one ***Main.xml*** file in which your ***ListView*** will be.

2) After that according to your snapshot you have to also make another layout named ***custom.xml*** file in which you have to take horizontal Linear Layout with three check-boxes. You can adjust view with your requirement.

3)Finally you can inflate that custom.xml file to your ***Main.xml*** file for ***ListView***.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listview.xml where keep your listview only and create another xml for only one row and inflate it using adapter.

[click here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)

you can check this link, here they used customized listview